# How to format local time to mm/dd/yyyy HH:MM:SS AM/PM in Perl

Tags: perl, datetime

I need to convert the local time to exact format as `mm/dd/yyyy HH:MM:SS AM/PM`.

```
my ($sec,$min,$hour,$mday,$mon,$year,$wday,$yday,$isdst) = localtime();
```

Comment: How about some https://www.google.com/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#newwindow=1&q=perl+format+date+time

Comment: I feel compelled to point out that what you've asked for has the date fields in a nonsensical order. Surely it would make more sense to arrange the units either smallest-to-largest (DD/MM/YYYY) or largest-to-smallest (YYYY-MM-DD).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By using `strftime` of [POSIX](http://perldoc.perl.org/POSIX.html) module you can get the desire result:

```
use POSIX qw/strftime/;
print strftime('%d-%m-%Y %I:%M:%S %p',localtime);
```

Comment: It's worth pointing out that the `%` sequences in the format string are documented in [the strftime manual page](http://linux.die.net/man/3/strftime).

Answer (score 3):

I would suggest the [`Time::Piece`](http://perldoc.perl.org/Time/Piece.html) module (which is core):

```
use Time::Piece;
print localtime -> strftime("%d-%m-%Y %I:%M:%S %p");
```

Answer (score 1):

One option:

```
use POSIX qw(strftime);

my $date = strftime "%m/%d/%Y %I:%M:%S %p", localtime;
print $date;
```

[See it in action](http://ideone.com/ngwdV3)

Answer (score 1):

You could use the powerfull [DateTime](https://metacpan.org/pod/DateTime) library and it's [strftime](https://metacpan.org/pod/DateTime#dt-strftime-format)-function.

```
use DateTime;
my $dt = DateTime->now(); # Defaults to now
my $string = $dt->strftime("%m/%d/%Y %l:%M:%S %p");
print "The Time: $string\n";
```